# How to import Maven project to eclipse workspace?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any Maven command or DOS command to import a Maven projects to eclipse workspace?

We can do it manually in eclipse by using following steps

1. Open Eclipse IDE in Java perspective
2. In package explorer --> right click--> `Import` --> `Existing maven projects` --> `Browse for project` --> `next` --> (Fix errors if any by add to POM) --> `Finish`.

Can we achieve the above by using any command?

Comment: `mvn eclipse:eclipse` will do it for you

Answer (score 4):

You can execute :

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

this will generate all eclipse configuration files. then you can import project classicaly in your IDE.

But no command to make eclipse known your project without importing it from IDE.